# Azure PaaS to PaaS network communication

Tags: azure, paas

When an Azure PaaS service (ex:App Service)  makes a call to another PaaS service in the same region, say SQL Database, is that traffic routed through Public Internet or routed entirely through Azure backbone network (like: for DNS resolution and other subsequent network hops). Is there any difference in the way this traffic is routed if the services are in different regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, so I thought it will help the community if someone has the same question.

The PaaS - PaaS traffic stays entirely within Azure backbone network.
Link [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/global-network/#features)

[image: From the Microsoft website]